# Why dask shows smaller size than the actual size of the data (numpy array)?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-distributed

`Dask` shows slightly smaller size than the actual size of a numpy array. Here is an example of a `numpy` array that is exactly 32 Mb:

```
import dask as da
import dask.array
import numpy as np

shape = (1000,4000)
ones_np = np.ones(shape)
print(f"Size:{ones_np.nbytes / 1e6} Mb")
>> Size: 32.0 Mb
```

However with Dask it shows 30.52:

```
ones_da = da.array.ones(shape)
ones_da
```

[image]

Tho if I do `ones_da.nbytes/1e6` it returns the correct (32 Mb) size.

I thought dask Array size should show the actual size?

Comment: MiB is different from Mb?

Comment: 1 MiB = 1,048,576 bytes

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice that! Is there a way to ask dask to show Mb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function responsible is [here in dask/utils](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/dask/utils.py#L1777) ([permalink](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/1b711beb3985efd7b895db2709c7b7cd869216f0/dask/utils.py#L1777)) and it only supports powers of 2, not 10. This in contrast to the time units immediately below. You could ask for this to be a configurable thing, but someone would have to put in a little work.